# Where do I put assets for my python tests?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python. I'm trying to set up tests for my python classes using nose. Where do I put assets for my tests?

Ok so lets say I have a class that manipulates an image. I have an image for each test. Where would I put these images for my tests?
I don't want them in my production environment. They are only for testing purposes.

Comment: @Ziz, nothing wrong with writing tests for python classes.

Comment: I usually just drop to `tests` folder with test modules. See *yaml* files here: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/src/bf2c3affa5528c6e96bfcc96b0caf4b0c9a9ec27/cryptoassets/core/tests/?at=master

Comment: Personally I have a 'data' folder. If data is not shared between files and there are multiple files per script or even class, then you could consider having 'test_myscript_data' for each of 'myscript' (i would make them subfolders of data as well). Also, avoid assests as much as you can with unit tests: they make maintenance a nightmare. For the cases where you don't have a choice, Mikko's comment tends to be the norm. Do whatever you must to keep it clean yet clear what is needed by which test.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to have two folders beside each other to keep your work-space cleaner, one for your python source files (`src/`), and one for your testing assets (`res/`).

It might look a little something like this.

```
src/
    main.py
res/
    image.png
```

It certainly looks pretty clean! But how are you going to grab that image if it's not in the same folder as your `main.py` file?

Simple solution, you can use [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) command using the Python `os` library.

`os.chdir("../res")`

What that does is it changes your current working directory to the requested folder. So if you wanted to grab that image file, all you would have to do is use the path `"image.png"`.